# Cannot ping other addresses after DHCP lease

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, wpa-supplicant, dhclient

I’m trying to connect my Arch Linux laptop to the WiFi at my school, but it isn’t working. WPA supplicant doesn’t report any errors, and dhclient is able to get me an IP address. But after that, I can’t ping the outside world, the provided name servers, I can’t even ping the gateway. Is it possible my school put me in a vLAN jail?

EDIT: Looking through wireshark, the DNS server and my laptop talk to each other, but even trying to ping that server has the same result

Comment: Read `man ip ip-route`. Sounds like you are missing a `default` route.

Comment: @waltinator the route is added automagically, even if it wasn’t I should be able to ping other devices in the LAN without a gateway.

Comment: Any actual value to provide? eg `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route; ip neigh; ip rule`?

Comment: @A.B ip link shows my WiFi interface is up, ip address shows that I have both an IPv4 and IPv6 address, ip route routes default via 10.187.0.1, ip neigh and ip rule I haven’t tried yet and will have to wait until Monday. I also tried changing my MAC address, but unfortunately no dice on that one either.